# How to make Entity Framework code first serialize a property list

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework

I have a class to save to database using codefirst ef, as follows

```
public class Book
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

it works fine, except it does not generate any column for the Dictionary. I want it to make a varchar(max) and I want it to convert my dictionary into JSON and write the JSON string into the column.

How is the easiest way to do that?  I suppose I can add a dummy string like this...

```
    public string PropertiesJson;
    public Dictionary<string, object> Properties
    {
        get { return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(PropertiesJson); }
        set { PropertiesJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value); }
    }
```

And the string will get written to the database. However this has several problems. The string might get stale if someone adds to the dictionary, and the logic isn't properly lazy, etc.

And I want to use the paradigm for the columns in several tables, so I'd like to have a simple plug in type. For example,

```
    public PropertyDictionary Properties { get; set; }
```

in which `PropertyDictionary` is a type with which EF will automatically do the right thing.  is that the best way?  How can I do that?

Comment: If you need to keep json in the database you are probably doing something wrong

Comment: @RoyalBg I disagree. You don't know the case and why. We don't have to know. We simply need a solution.

Comment: I think the OP needs to keep arbitrary properties for a book. I would suggest a table that has columns for `key` and `value` and a relation to the book

Comment: @RoyalBg, I wouldn't say "wrong". Sometimes you do have a complex type that is a value-object and you don't care to persist its serialized representation to the database. Also, SQL Server 2016 will support JSON natively.

Comment: Well, if it's completely necessary, my solution would be a string column which is a property and a private dictionary property behind, which has exposed Add/Remove methods. The Add method could append to the string, or serialize the dictionary which is not lazy enough. One can also override the `SaveChanges()` method which will serialize the dictionary before calling `base.SaveChanges()`

Comment: @RoyalBg granted. Perhaps someday someone will want to query the data inside the JSON. But today nobody wants to do that. And don't assume the the value is simple either. In JSON the value can be an object or a list also.

Comment: It could be, but as I have seen the dictionary pairs were string=>string :) I was trying to provide a solution for the given problem, not for a problem that does not exist :-) If key => value columns are not good enough, because the value might be a list, you might want to add different values (rows) for the same `BookId` and `Key`. If the value has certain relation, you might need another column that related to another table. I think all the treelike structure could be represented as a normal relational database. However, the dictionary serialization upon savechanges seems fine for me? :)

Comment: @RoyalBg i didn't know i could override SaveChanges. That's useful! I like your idea of a private dict also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your code :

```
public string PropertiesJson;
public Dictionary<string, object> Properties
{
    get { return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(PropertiesJson); }
    set { PropertiesJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value); }
}
```

... cannot work in my opinion because you don't `set` the value each time you add or edit a key/value in your dictionary.

Instead, what I would try is to have a `string` property so it will be persisted. First problem solved.

Then, I would manually bind the `get` on the `Dictionary` like this:

```
protected string _propertiesJson;
public string PropertiesJson
{
    get {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Properties);
    }
    set {
        _propertiesJson = value;
        Properties = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(value);
    }
}

protected Dictionary<string, object> _properties;
public Dictionary<string, object> Properties
{
    get 
    {
        if (_properties != null)
        {
            return _properties;
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_propertiesJson))
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(_propertiesJson);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    set 
    { 
        _properties = value; 
    }
}
```

Note that this code was not tested and is a start of something I would try.

The string should only be used by Entity Framework to persist your dictionary. You should not try to edit both.  The general idea here is that you use the dictionary and let Entity Framework do the job.

It's a start.

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution I've chosen. Except I do not keep a copy of string  _propertiesJson, and the dictionary is simply { get; set; }.

Comment: You are right, I had code that was not needed.  But you took the best out of the answer! :-)

Comment: It is unfortunate that I have to copy and paste this code into several classes. I wish there were a way to factor it out into another class, for instance, PropertyDictionary. Hopefully EF will soon be enhanced to allow a better way to do this.

Comment: I did that with inheritance by using an abstract class.  That way, you don't alter your schema and EF sees it as one object instead of two. You might want to dig that topic.

Comment: I thought of that, but with inheritance I only get one. Sometimes I have a class that contains two property dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this answer will be not fine for you but I would create the DataAccess class which will be the same as database schema. So I would introduce it like that:

```
public class Book
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Properties { get; set; }
}
```

And for my domain classes I would use the Dictionary collection.
Before I would save data I would use for example the AutoMapper to serialize the collection.

This solution for me would be the clearest. Data access will be close to what you have in DB and the domain model will be easy to use in domain logic.